# convert a .xlsb file to .csv file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file from which I need to pick up a specific sheet and then convert that sheet to .csv format. The data looks like like this:

[image]

This sheet has other tables below Overall but I am not interested in those. I want to simply pick up the Overall table and store the values into a .csv file. I cannot change the input format or anything of that sort.

Until now, I have figured out how to pick a specific sheet from an excel file. But I am struggling with picking up only a single table from that sheet. This is what I have for now:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyxlsb import open_workbook as open_xlsb



#first handle xls case 
xls = pd.ExcelFile('sample.xlsx') #workbook has 2 sheets: sheet 1 and sheet 2
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet2')
#print(df1.head())
#print(df2.head())
```

Example data https://drive.google.com/file/d/18uEai4NYHZVdxY4BtrB8oGqDbSIbZ6kX/view?usp=sharing

```
| overall | a   | b   | c  | d   |
|---------|-----|-----|----|-----|
| row 1   | 1   | 2   | 6  | 2   |
| row 2   | 2   | 5   | 2  | 4   |
| row 3   | 5   | 7   | 3  | 6   |
| row 4   | 7   | 8   | 3  | 7   |
|         |     |     |    |     |

| table 2 | l   | m   | n  | o   |
| row 1   | 1   | 35  | 5  | 887 |
| row 2   | 232 | 3   | 35 | 8   |
| row 3   | 2   | 5   | 5  | 6   |
| row 4   | 14  | 546 | 78 | 2   |
```

Comment: A screenshot of your `.xlsb` may not be suffiscient in your case. Can you share a sample of  your dataset and/or show the number/name of rows/columns of the concerned sheet ?

Comment: @abokey added. in the example data, I want to pick up only the table called Overall and convert all the data from the table into a .csv file

Comment: Can't you share a sample in the `.xlsb` format ?

Comment: You don't need Python for your task. Everything can be done with excel. Save the desired page to a new file, then the file "save as ..." and select csv.

Comment: @СергейКох i know how to do it using excel. The reason i want to automate it is because i have 1000s of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`pandas.read_excel`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and pass `engine = 'pyxlsb'` as a parameter to read a fixed specific range (rows/columns) from a `.xlsb` file.

**Note** : *There is no [structured references (tables)](https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/structured-references-in-excel/) in your `.xlsb`. There is only range of values.*

```
import pandas as pd

#pip install pyxlsb
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsb', sheet_name='Summary_Detailed', skiprows=range(0,3), usecols='B:G', engine='pyxlsb')

df = df.iloc[0:41,:].dropna(subset='Overall') #to select the rows

df.to_csv('sample.csv', index=False) #to generate a .csv file
```

##### `>>> display(df)`

[image]

Let me know if you need to load more columns than `B` to `G`.